# Iterating over a Database

Tags: python, iteration

I want to iterate over a list.

```
def Alle_Eintraege_Anzeigen():
    for Text in Schluesselanlegen.select():
        print (str(Text.Schluessel))
    for Text in Schluesselanlegen.select():
        print (str(Text.Schwierigkeitsgrad)) 
    for Date in Schluesselanlegen.select():
        print (str(Date.Oeffnungsdatum))
```

At the end it should look like this:

```
1|Schluessel1|2|23.01.2017
2|Schluessel2|3|24.01.2017
```

How can i do it ?

is something in my order wrong ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to print once per line

```
def Alle_Eintraege_Anzeigen():
    for Text in Schluesselanlegen.select():
        print (str(Text.Schluessel))+'|'+(str(Text.Schwierigkeitsgrad))+'|'+(str(Date.Oeffnungsdatum))
```

Also, you might want to keep a counter variable to print the line number

```
def Alle_Eintraege_Anzeigen():
    lineNumber = 1
    for Text in Schluesselanlegen.select():
        print (str(lineNumber))+'|'+(str(Text.Schluessel))+'|'+(str(Text.Schwierigkeitsgrad))+'|'+(str(Date.Oeffnungsdatum))
        lineNumber += 1
```

(I assumed you literally wanted to print the pipe characters)